# Delphi windows 7 control panel component

Tags: delphi, windows-7, controls, vcl

Im looking for a delphi component that looks and functions like the Windows 7 control panel buttons when you "view by category".  Anybody know if something like this already exists?

[image]

Comment: I want to create a menu in my own software that functions like the control panel links

Comment: Can you help me with [this problem][1]? I had black background and Chinese letters.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661712/problems-with-ttaskbutton-control-panel-component-in-lazarus-delphi

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just created a small component that looks sort of what you want. It is double-buffered, and hence completely flicker-free, and works both with visual themes enabled and disabled.

```
unit TaskButton;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Forms, Messages, Windows, Graphics, Classes, Controls, UxTheme,
  ImgList, PNGImage;

type
  TIconSource = (isImageList, isPNGImage);

  TTaskButtonLinkClickEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; LinkIndex: integer) of object;

  TTaskButton = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCaption: TCaption;
    FHeaderRect: TRect;
    FImageSpacing: integer;
    FLinks: TStrings;
    FHeaderHeight: integer;
    FLinkHeight: integer;
    FLinkSpacing: integer;
    FHeaderSpacing: integer;
    FLinkRects: array of TRect;
    FPrevMouseHoverIndex: integer;
    FMouseHoverIndex: integer;
    FImages: TImageList;
    FImageIndex: TImageIndex;
    FIconSource: TIconSource;
    FImage: TPngImage;
    FBuffer: TBitmap;
    FOnLinkClick: TTaskButtonLinkClickEvent;
    procedure UpdateMetrics;
    procedure SetCaption(const Caption: TCaption);
    procedure SetImageSpacing(ImageSpacing: integer);
    procedure SetLinkSpacing(LinkSpacing: integer);
    procedure SetHeaderSpacing(HeaderSpacing: integer);
    procedure SetLinks(Links: TStrings);
    procedure SetImages(Images: TImageList);
    procedure SetImageIndex(ImageIndex: TImageIndex);
    procedure SetIconSource(IconSource: TIconSource);
    procedure SetImage(Image: TPngImage);
    procedure SwapBuffers;
    function ImageWidth: integer;
    function ImageHeight: integer;
    procedure SetNonThemedHeaderFont;
    procedure SetNonThemedLinkFont(Hovering: boolean = false);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Caption: TCaption read FCaption write SetCaption;
    property Links: TStrings read FLinks write SetLinks;
    property ImageSpacing: integer read FImageSpacing write SetImageSpacing default 16;
    property HeaderSpacing: integer read FHeaderSpacing write SetHeaderSpacing default 2;
    property LinkSpacing: integer read FLinkSpacing write SetLinkSpacing default 2;
    property Images: TImageList read FImages write SetImages;
    property ImageIndex: TImageIndex read FImageIndex write SetImageIndex;
    property Image: TPngImage read FImage write SetImage;
    property IconSource: TIconSource read FIconSource write SetIconSource default isPNGImage;
    property OnLinkClick: TTaskButtonLinkClickEvent read FOnLinkClick write FOnLinkClick;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Math;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TTaskButton]);
end;

function IsIntInInterval(x, xmin, xmax: integer): boolean; inline;
begin
  IsIntInInterval := (xmin <= x) and (x <= xmax);
end;

function PointInRect(const Point: TPoint; const Rect: TRect): boolean; inline;
begin
  PointInRect := IsIntInInterval(Point.X, Rect.Left, Rect.Right) and
                 IsIntInInterval(Point.Y, Rect.Top, Rect.Bottom);
end;

{ TTaskButton }

constructor TTaskButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  InitThemeLibrary;
  FBuffer := TBitmap.Create;
  FLinks := TStringList.Create;
  FImage := TPngImage.Create;
  FImageSpacing := 16;
  FHeaderSpacing := 2;
  FLinkSpacing := 2;
  FPrevMouseHoverIndex := -1;
  FMouseHoverIndex := -1;
  FIconSource := isPNGImage;
end;

destructor TTaskButton.Destroy;
begin
  FLinkRects := nil;
  FImage.Free;
  FLinks.Free;
  FBuffer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TTaskButton.ImageHeight: integer;
begin

  result := 0;
  case FIconSource of
    isImageList:
      if Assigned(FImages) then
        result := FImages.Height;
    isPNGImage:
      if Assigned(FImage) then
        result := FImage.Height;
  end;

end;

function TTaskButton.ImageWidth: integer;
begin

  result := 0;
  case FIconSource of
    isImageList:
      if Assigned(FImages) then
        result := FImages.Width;
    isPNGImage:
      if Assigned(FImage) then
        result := FImage.Width;
  end;

end;

procedure TTaskButton.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  Paint;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FMouseHoverIndex := -1;
  for i := 0 to high(FLinkRects) do
    if PointInRect(point(X, Y), FLinkRects[i]) then
    begin
      FMouseHoverIndex := i;
      break;
    end;

  if FMouseHoverIndex <> FPrevMouseHoverIndex then
  begin
    Cursor := IfThen(FMouseHoverIndex <> -1, crHandPoint, crDefault);
    Paint;
  end;

  FPrevMouseHoverIndex := FMouseHoverIndex;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  Paint;
  if (FMouseHoverIndex <> -1) and Assigned(FOnLinkClick) then
    FOnLinkClick(Self, FMouseHoverIndex);
end;

procedure TTaskButton.Paint;
var
  theme: HTHEME;
  i: Integer;
  pnt: TPoint;
  r: PRect;
begin
  inherited;

  if FLinks.Count <> length(FLinkRects) then
    UpdateMetrics;

  FBuffer.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  FBuffer.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);


  if GetCursorPos(pnt) then
    if PointInRect(Self.ScreenToClient(pnt), ClientRect) then
    begin

      if UxTheme.UseThemes then
      begin

        theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
        if theme <> 0  then
          try
            DrawThemeBackground(theme,
                                FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                                BP_COMMANDLINK,
                                CMDLS_HOT,
                                ClientRect,
                                nil);
          finally
            CloseThemeData(theme);
          end;

      end
      else
      begin

        New(r);
        try
          r^ := ClientRect;
          DrawEdge(FBuffer.Canvas.Handle, r^, EDGE_RAISED, BF_RECT);
        finally
          Dispose(r);
        end;

      end;

    end;

  case FIconSource of
    isImageList:
      if Assigned(FImages) then
        FImages.Draw(FBuffer.Canvas, 14, 16, FImageIndex);
    isPNGImage:
      if Assigned(FImage) then
        FBuffer.Canvas.Draw(14, 16, FImage);
  end;

  if UxTheme.UseThemes then
  begin

    theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'CONTROLPANEL');

    if theme <> 0 then
      try

        DrawThemeText(theme,
                      FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                      CPANEL_SECTIONTITLELINK,
                      CPSTL_NORMAL,
                      PChar(Caption),
                      length(Caption),
                      DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE,
                      0,
                      FHeaderRect);

        for i := 0 to FLinks.Count - 1 do
          DrawThemeText(theme,
                        FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                        CPANEL_CONTENTLINK,
                        IfThen(FMouseHoverIndex = i, IfThen(csLButtonDown in ControlState, CPCL_PRESSED, CPCL_HOT), CPCL_NORMAL),
                        PChar(FLinks[i]),
                        length(FLinks[i]),
                        DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE,
                        0,
                        FLinkRects[i]
                       );

      finally
        CloseThemeData(theme);
      end;

  end
  else
  begin

    SetNonThemedHeaderFont;
    DrawText(FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
             PChar(Caption),
             -1,
             FHeaderRect,
             DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE);

    for i := 0 to FLinks.Count - 1 do
    begin
      SetNonThemedLinkFont(FMouseHoverIndex = i);
      DrawText(FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
               PChar(FLinks[i]),
               -1,
               FLinkRects[i],
               DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE);
    end;

  end;

  SwapBuffers;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetCaption(const Caption: TCaption);
begin
  if not SameStr(FCaption, Caption) then
  begin
    FCaption := Caption;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetHeaderSpacing(HeaderSpacing: integer);
begin
  if FHeaderSpacing <> HeaderSpacing then
  begin
    FHeaderSpacing := HeaderSpacing;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetIconSource(IconSource: TIconSource);
begin
  if FIconSource <> IconSource then
  begin
    FIconSource := IconSource;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetImage(Image: TPngImage);
begin
  FImage.Assign(Image);
  UpdateMetrics;
  Paint;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetImageIndex(ImageIndex: TImageIndex);
begin
  if FImageIndex <> ImageIndex then
  begin
    FImageIndex := ImageIndex;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetImages(Images: TImageList);
begin
  FImages := Images;
  UpdateMetrics;
  Paint;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetImageSpacing(ImageSpacing: integer);
begin
  if FImageSpacing <> ImageSpacing then
  begin
    FImageSpacing := ImageSpacing;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetLinks(Links: TStrings);
begin
  FLinks.Assign(Links);
  UpdateMetrics;
  Paint;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetLinkSpacing(LinkSpacing: integer);
begin
  if FLinkSpacing <> LinkSpacing then
  begin
    FLinkSpacing := LinkSpacing;
    UpdateMetrics;
    Paint;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SwapBuffers;
begin
  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, FBuffer.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TTaskButton.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_SIZE:
      UpdateMetrics;
    CM_MOUSEENTER:
      Paint;
    CM_MOUSELEAVE:
      Paint;
    WM_ERASEBKGND:
      Message.Result := 1;
  end;
end;


procedure TTaskButton.UpdateMetrics;
var
  theme: HTHEME;
  cr, r: TRect;
  i, y: Integer;
begin

  FBuffer.SetSize(Width, Height);
  SetLength(FLinkRects, FLinks.Count);

  if UxTheme.UseThemes then
  begin

    theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'CONTROLPANEL');

    if theme <> 0 then
      try

        with cr do
        begin
          Top := 10;
          Left := ImageWidth + FImageSpacing;
          Right := Width - 4;
          Bottom := Self.Height;
        end;

        GetThemeTextExtent(theme,
                           FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                           CPANEL_SECTIONTITLELINK,
                           CPSTL_NORMAL,
                           PChar(Caption),
                           -1,
                           DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE,
                           @cr,
                           r);

        FHeaderHeight := r.Bottom - r.Top;

        with FHeaderRect do
        begin
          Top := 10;
          Left := 14 + ImageWidth + FImageSpacing;
          Right := Width - 4;
          Bottom := Top + FHeaderHeight;
        end;

        with cr do
        begin
          Top := 4;
          Left := 14 + ImageWidth + FImageSpacing;
          Right := Width - 4;
          Bottom := Self.Height;
        end;

        y := FHeaderRect.Bottom + FHeaderSpacing;
        for i := 0 to high(FLinkRects) do
        begin

          GetThemeTextExtent(theme,
                             FBuffer.Canvas.Handle,
                             CPANEL_CONTENTLINK,
                             CPCL_NORMAL,
                             PChar(FLinks[i]),
                             -1,
                             DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_TOP or DT_SINGLELINE,
                             @cr,
                             r);

          FLinkHeight := r.Bottom - r.Top;

          FLinkRects[i].Left := FHeaderRect.Left;
          FLinkRects[i].Top := y;
          FLinkRects[i].Right := FLinkRects[i].Left + r.Right - r.Left;
          FLinkRects[i].Bottom := FLinkRects[i].Top + FLinkHeight + FLinkSpacing;

          inc(y, FLinkHeight + FLinkSpacing);
        end;

      finally
        CloseThemeData(theme);
      end;
  end
  else
  begin

    SetNonThemedHeaderFont;

    FHeaderHeight := FBuffer.Canvas.TextHeight(FCaption);

    with FHeaderRect do
    begin
      Top := 10;
      Left := 14 + ImageWidth + FImageSpacing;
      Right := Width - 4;
      Bottom := Top + FHeaderHeight;
    end;

    SetNonThemedLinkFont;

    y := FHeaderRect.Bottom + FHeaderSpacing;
    for i := 0 to high(FLinkRects) do
      with FBuffer.Canvas.TextExtent(FLinks[i]) do
      begin

        FLinkHeight := cy;

        FLinkRects[i].Left := FHeaderRect.Left;
        FLinkRects[i].Top := y;
        FLinkRects[i].Right := FLinkRects[i].Left + cx;
        FLinkRects[i].Bottom := FLinkRects[i].Top + FLinkHeight + FLinkSpacing;

        inc(y, FLinkHeight + FLinkSpacing);
      end;

  end;

end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetNonThemedHeaderFont;
begin
  with FBuffer.Canvas.Font do
  begin
    Color := clNavy;
    Style := [];
    Size := 14;
  end;
end;

procedure TTaskButton.SetNonThemedLinkFont(Hovering: boolean = false);
begin
  with FBuffer.Canvas.Font do
  begin
    Color := clNavy;
    if Hovering then
      Style := [fsUnderline]
    else
      Style := [];
    Size := 10;
  end;
end;

initialization
  // Override Delphi's ugly hand cursor with the nice Windows hand cursor
  Screen.Cursors[crHandPoint] := LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND);


end.
```

Screenshots:

[image: Image of TTaskButton]

[image: Image of TTaskButton (unthemed)]

If I get time over I will add a keyboard interface to it.

Comment: Where can I get PNGImage? Looks like there is a licensing problem?

Comment: If I recall correctly, PNGImage was added in Delphi 2009. What version of Delphi are you running?

Comment: I found PngImage 1.56 by Gustavo. Gustavo's main PNG object is named TPngObject and CodeGear's class is named TPngImage in delphi 2009. I tried changing your code to use PngObject instead, but after installing your component it is still not working in Delphi 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea about how `TPngObject` is working, but it probably should work (what else would the class be for? :) ). Also, theming support, in particular, the UxTheme unit, didn't exist in Delphi 7. But that is only a minor problem, because it only contained the signatures of functions in Windows API. You can use these functions without this unit. If you want your application to be compatible with older versions of Windows (such as XP), you should call these functions via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. This is standard procedures, so there should be a lot of sites explaining this in a

Comment: I know that this is an old answer - but I have an issue when porting this code to Delphi XE2 - the header doesn't draw - everything else does! Any ideas ?

Comment: @mmmm Only additional 9 years later: The culprit is evil `with`. Either dissolve all uses of `with` (at least for `TRect`s) or replace `Width` with `Self.Width` inside them.

Comment: FWIW: I replaced `TImageList` with `TDragImageList`. Then even DevEx cxImageLists work. ;-)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Do you have an updated version of this component?

Comment: @UliGerhardt: No, I just wrote it for this Q and have never used it myself. Anything in particular you would like to change or fix?

Comment: No, I just stumbled over it and felt compelled to play with it. ;-)  Just didn't want to miss any potential improvements. I like how you're always throwing out these little components.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a customized **ListView** with activated *Tile View*.

See ["About List-View Controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#ListView_Styles_and_Views) on *MSDN*.

Comment: You are right. It does look like a listView in Tile view, I did not even notice it before.

Answer (score 0):

That is part of the Windows shell. It looks like [these components](http://www.jam-software.com/shellbrowser_delphi/) wrap the windows shell functionality.

Comment: I downloaded the JAM software component demos but they did not provide the functionality that I need.