# CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) vs DEP (Data Execution Prevention)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium-embedded, dep

I'm using DCEF3 (https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/) with Delphi 7.

The CEF version, embedded with the DCEF, is 3.1547.1412.

**The Problem**

On machines with Windows 2008 R2, some times when my application loads, it crashes with an event of type **BEX**.

I only was able to solve the crash **deactivating the DEP on windows**, for this I used the prompt command:

```
bdcedit /set nx AlwaysOff
```

But this cannot be the solution.

I cannot force my users to **disable** DEP on their servers.

Here is the APPCRASH report (in Portuguese):

```
    Assinatura do problema:
      Nome do Evento de Problema:         BEX
      Nome do Aplicativo:                          MyExecutable.exe
      Versão do Aplicativo:                         1.1.0.1
      Carimbo de Data/Hora do Aplicativo:            2a425e19
      Nome do Módulo de Falhas:            dhcpcsvc6.DLL
      Versão do Módulo de Falhas:           6.1.7601.17970
      Carimbo de Data/Hora do Módulo de Falhas:              50745f7c
      Deslocamento de Exceção:               00001730
      Código de Exceção:                            c0000005
      Dados de Exceção:                             00000008
      Versão do sistema operacional:        6.1.7601.2.1.0.18.10
      Identificação da Localidade:             1046
      Informações Adicionais 1:                 a7aa
      Informações Adicionais 2:                 a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d
      Informações Adicionais 3:                 a7aa
      Informações Adicionais 4:                 a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d
```

Can somebody help me to find the root of the problem or some information about why this is happening?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a small test app with Chromium embedded?  If so it will be far easier for people here to answer. Your big app could be doing any number of things that interact badly with CEF. You're looking for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which can be hard by the time you embed components, but please do your best.

Comment: Also [this article indicates that SysUtils in Delphi 7 can trigger DEP](http://www.prestwood.com/ASPSuite/KB/Document_View.asp?QID=100651), and you need to upgrade to D2005 or later to fix it. (However, the article does link to a patch.)  Delphi 7 is incredibly ancient, so it's no surprise it does stuff that's not acceptable on versions of Windows written after it was released. My standard suggestion to anyone using D7 is to upgrade anyway :)

Comment: @David: this problem starts happening after I embedded CEF, and I cannot migrate to a newer delphi. I will try to create a test app, but I don't guarantee that I will reproduce the problem..

Comment: Take a look on http://www.infoworld.com/d/security/malware-abuses-chromium-embedded-framework-developers-fight-back-215190 and http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this articles:

- [Delphi applications and the TSAWARE header flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517022/delphi-applications-and-the-tsaware-header-flag)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2279689

I added the following directive to add to the header the TSAWARE info:

```
{$SETPEOPTFLAGS $8000}
```

After some exhaustive tests, the problem stopped.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you link to a [forum that explains that Chromium intentionally enables data execution prevention](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11247) by calling [`SetProcessDEPPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736299.aspx). [DEP is known to interfere with Delphi 7.](http://www.prestwood.com/ASPSuite/KB/Document_View.asp?QID=100651) In that light, I see three solutions (listed in descending preference order):

1. Upgrade to a version of Delphi that's less than a decade old. You'll get an RTL that's DEP-aware.
2. As mentioned in the forum, compile Chromium yourself and exclude the DEP-related code. You could do that, for example, by editing [`ApplyProcessMitigationsToCurrentProcess` in *process_mitigations.cc*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/sandbox/win/src/process_mitigations.cc&l=31) to make it ignore the `MITIGATION_DEP` and `MITIGATION_DEP_NO_ATL_THUNK` flags.
3. Run [bcdedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667.aspx), as you've already found. When you do that, you disable DEP at the OS level, and that forces Chromium's calls to `SetProcessDEPPolicy` to fail.

Comment: (6 years later..) So, I have a similar problem, but with a different problem child legacy DLL. I tried your suggestion of recompiling Chrome with the DEP code removed. The problem is, that the code you identified above doesn't ship as part of CEF. The only Chromium dll shipped appears to be chrome_elf.dll. The code identified above gets compiled out into sandbox.dll. Unless, this then gets somehow combined into one of the CEF libraries, this seems to be a dead-end.